# bumpless transfer for a family of PIDs

Tags: simulink, pid-controller

I have a family of PID controllers (around 100), each designed based on an operating point. During implementation, I am using interpolation. However, still the transfer is not bumpless.

How do we implement a family of PIDs with bumpless transfer?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your control scheme. Are you interpolating between all controller outputs? Just a first guess (but I would need to see your exact implementation): the disconnected PIDs should be set to tracking mode (tracking the output of the connected PID) and when the switch happens, the transfer would be bumpless.

Comment: Here's a doc for PID tracking mode: http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/examples/bumpless-control-transfer-between-manual-and-pid-control.html

Answer (score 0):

The [PID tracking mode](http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/examples/bumpless-control-transfer-between-manual-and-pid-control.html) is a common solution for bumpless transfer.